# Should a colon character be escaped in TEXT values in iCalendar (rfc2445)?

Tags: standards, escaping, icalendar, rfc2445

My understanding from reading the specification (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) is that the ":" character should **not** be escaped in text values like DESCRIPTION.

From the RFC:

> The "TEXT" property values may also
>   contain special characters that    are
>   used to signify delimiters, such as a
>   COMMA character for lists    of values
>   or a SEMICOLON character for
>   structured values. In order to
>   support the inclusion of these special
>   characters in "TEXT" property
>   values, they MUST be escaped with a
>   BACKSLASH character. A BACKSLASH
>   character (US-ASCII decimal 92) in a
>   "TEXT" property value MUST be
>   escaped with another BACKSLASH
>   character. A COMMA character in a
>   "TEXT" property value MUST be escaped
>   with a BACKSLASH character
>   (US-ASCII decimal 92). A SEMICOLON
>   character in a "TEXT" property
>   value MUST be escaped with a BACKSLASH
>   character (US-ASCII decimal    92). 
>   However, a COLON character in a "TEXT"
>   property value SHALL NOT    be escaped
>   with a BACKSLASH character.

I ask this because I'm receiving syntax errors in Meeting Maker v8.7.1b63 for Mac OS X due to this character but not for the Windows version of the software (same version number). It's choking on ics files I'm generating from software I've written. Is this a bug in my software of theirs?

This is the iCalendar file that is receiving the error:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//abc/abc//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1234_abcd@abc.abc
DTSTART:20091022T133000
DTEND:20091022T150000
SUMMARY:Special Topics in Power Point
LOCATION:The Location 
DESCRIPTION:Learn how to use PowerPoint as a tool to organize and pres
 ent your ideas to others.  Basic computer skills are required.  This h
 ands-on workshop will provide you with experience in the following: wh
 at's new in PowerPoint 2007\, presentation basics\, working with text
 \, viewing a presentation\, formatting\, finalizing a presentation and
  delivering a presentation.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Note the colon on the third line of the description.  Adding a slash to this colon fixes the problem on the Mac but I think this is incorrect according to the standard.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in their software.

> "However, a COLON character in a
>   "TEXT" property value SHALL NOT be
>   escaped with a BACKSLASH character."

Is pretty straightforward.

See if they have any patches. 
If not, try to contact them and tell them about it.

Comment: I discussed my question with the vendor and they confirmed that this is a bug in that version of their software. ":" does *not* need to be escaped.